# Opencpu and R-statistics

Tags: r, opencpu

I am wanting to use OpenCpu to do statistical web-based apps.
BUT, the documentation I see on the web seems to be contradictory.
Just trying to get started is difficult for a newbie.
I hope someone knows how.
I have seen some posts here on stackoverflow, and I still see contradictions.
Note that I have used Rserve in java and Rpy2 in python, and these are wrappers to R-stats.

BUT on the website I see that they say that OpenCpu is an embedded engine using HTTP.
I wish to install this OpenCpu on my local Ubuntu machine.

So my question is: 
(1)Does OpenCpu server contain some embedded version of R-statistics?
   SO the download contains everything i need.
OR 
(2)does one have to install R-statistics separately and the OpenCpu server separately,
so hence these are 2 separate applications that talk to one another over HTTP.

So you can see that I was not able to find this kind of fundamental starting knowledge on the web.

Comment: Does `apt-get install opencpu` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing `apt-get install opencpu` will automatically install R. Not because it is contained, but because it is declared as a dependency, so the package manager understands it needs R, apache, etc when it installs `opencpu`.

Comment: Hi Jeroen, I believe you are the developer of opencpu? Thanks for your response. So it is good that doing the apt-get will grab all things necessary. I see then that is a separately installed app. But when it says on the website that it is for 'embedded' scientific computing does that mean that opencpu and R will run in the same process somehow, or does opencpu and R will run in two separate processes and hence work as a client-server manner.

Comment: I recently installed R-statistics using apt-get on Ubuntu 14.04, and there were problems where one of the compiled library .so files used in R-statistics was placed in an incorrect folder and hence R did not work. After doing some research, the solution was to make a symbolic link in another folder elsewhere, where it is supposed to be in the first place. So I am wondering if I was to use 'apt-get install opencpu' on a fresh ubuntu that does not have R installed, will the installation process still make the same mistake that I encountered when installing R on its own.